# I could not read a property in php. getting non-object exception

Tags: php, laravel

I have defined a variable like `$alarm` in my php page. It returns like;
In my page I try to access **GradeName** , So calling like; (I want to extract all details from that returned alarm details)

```
 <div class=...
$alarm[0]['GradeName']
</div>
```

But Im getting

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /app/resources/views/alarms/ack.blade.php)
in c593810096345df8c818851d1e61ae4bc523a3d4.php (line 43)
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), 0)
in PhpEngine.php (line 44)
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/app/storage/framework/views/c593810096345df8c818851d1e61ae4bc523a3d4.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'alarm' => object(Alarm), 'yfSessionId' => '2OxcAqWMEGxuiYzjm2ox7Wmih2BP6HfrWdMXILmcdRjVsmiZSwBEhA=='))
in CompilerEngine.php (line 59)
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

```
{"AlarmId":173358,"MessageNotificationId":"105933",
"CompanyId":"33",
"CompanyCode":"EURO",
"AlertTypeId":"23",
"AlertId":"4314893",
"SiteCode":"20167822",
"SiteName":"Trafford Centre Service Station",
"TankNumber":null,
"DispenserNumbedr":null,
"HoseNumber":null,
"GradeId":null,
"GradeName":null}
```

If I do like this in my php class;

```
public function(){

**echo "<font color='red'><b>$alarm->CompanyCode</font></b><br>";**  //---------->I see this
   return view('alarms.ack', ['alarm' => $alarm, 'yfSessionId' => $yfSessionId]);
}
```

In my view if I access like I get non-object issue;

```
<div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Volume</label>

                                    <div class="col-md-6 control-label-text-left">

                                        {{ $alarm->AlarmVolume }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Did you parse the json? Like did you use json_decode?

Comment: what does `$alarm->GradeName` return ?

Comment: `[0]['GradeName']` isn't object notation.

Comment: @yoeunes I have edited my question with more detial

Comment: @Ratha your `$alarm` object does not have any property called `AlarmVolume` :/ check your json representation

Comment: @yoeunes It is there, I get big output, I provided a part of that. I suspect There is some other issue, the way I access the values

Comment: @Ratha can you please clean up your question, and also show how did you get the $alarm object in yourr function before sending it to the view

Comment: @yoeunes thanks a lot for your help. Actually issue was, one of the method in the model class  returns empty value(no data in db). It caused issue when loading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in errors it says `'alarm' => object(Alarm)` please try to access, your `GradeName` property like this : `$alarm->GradeName`

Comment: It works within code. Means in my php class  if I do like this; echo "<font color='red'><b>$alarm->CompanyCode</font></b><br>"; I can see my company code. But not in my view page. Same issue pops up